# webpack duplicate work during serving files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, development-environment

I've just faced to unpredictable situation during using custom webpack config.
I will try to explain the problem.

This is my simple app (file index.js):

```
console.log('!!this', this);
```

This is my webpack config (file webpack.config.js):

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              additionalData: `@import './src/constants/global';`,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: 'img/[name].[ext]' },
          },
          'image-webpack-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This is my npm script for launching the app (file package.json):

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
},
```

As a result I see the next picture - all code executes twice (index.js, VM787 index.js).
In addition to that, if I use data fetching callback in my app with this configuration, I will see two equal requests in the Network tab.

[image]

Who knows what is the reason for that and how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be result of StrictMode. It mounts, unmount and mount conponent again, to check if everything is running correctly. Try removing it from index.js (just to check). Mind that it's useful for its purpose, and it only has this behaviour in dev mode.

Comment: Nope. Strict mode is disabled actually

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing JavaScript into an HTML file yourself, you'll need to disable injection in the HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './public/index.html',
  inject: false,
}),
```